# Google Maps not displaying the actual map

Tags: swift, xcode, google-maps, dictionary

I have integrated the Google Maps API and SDK into my application. While just playing around and following some of Googles examples I noticed that everything works except the actual map view. So current location and nearby places is fully functioning. I have searched the web to find some answers, some said it could be your bundle ID that is incorrect, but that is not the case for me here.

Here is my code:

```
@IBAction func pickPlace(_ sender: AnyObject) {

    userLocation?.currentPlace(callback: { (placeLikelihoods, error) -> Void in
        guard error == nil else {
            print("Current Place error: \(error!.localizedDescription)")
            return
        }

        if let placeLikelihoods = placeLikelihoods {
            for likelihood in placeLikelihoods.likelihoods {
                let place = likelihood.place
                print("Current Place name \(place.name) at likelihood \(likelihood.likelihood)")
                print("Current Place address \(place.formattedAddress)")
                print("Current Place attributions \(place.attributions)")
                print("Current PlaceID \(place.placeID)")
            }
        }
    })

    let center = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(51.5108396, -0.0922251)
    let northEast = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(center.latitude + 0.001, center.longitude + 0.001)
    let southWest = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(center.latitude - 0.001, center.longitude - 0.001)
    let viewport = GMSCoordinateBounds(coordinate: northEast, coordinate: southWest)
    let config = GMSPlacePickerConfig(viewport: viewport)
    placePicker = GMSPlacePicker(config: config)

    placePicker?.pickPlace(callback: { (place: GMSPlace?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
        if let error = error {
            print("Pick Place error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
            return
        }

        if let place = place {
            print("Place name \(place.name)")
            print("Place address \(place.formattedAddress)")
            print("Place attributions \(place.attributions)")
        } else {
            print("No place selected")
        }
    })

}
```

Appreciate all the help I can get, thanks in advance!

Comment: "What API key have you enabled in your GDC? Did you receive any kind of errors?"

Comment: And I did not receive any errors.

Comment: you should enable this API, Google Maps SDK for iOS

Comment: It already is enabled, what I did though was that I created a new API with no bundle identifier. Now everything works! Thanks for your time!